# function "env" not defined

Tags: templates, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm pretty new to helm and go templates so please bear with me

I have a template called secrets.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: fooo-secrets
  labels:
    app: {{ template "fooo.name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
type: Opaque # TODO
data:
  SUPER_SECRET: {{env SUPER_SECRET | quote }} <--- the problem line
```

I got `env` from [sprig](https://godoc.org/github.com/Masterminds/sprig). The idea is that I can load up my secrets into my local environment and then deploy from there.

But when I lint my chart:

```
> helm lint fooo                                                   [13:29]
==> Linting fooo
[INFO] Chart.yaml: icon is recommended
[ERROR] templates/: parse error in "drone_ci/templates/secrets.yaml": template: drone_ci/templates/secrets.yaml:12: function "env" not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to pass this to a helm chart you should use values.

Instead of `{{env SUPER_SECRET | quote }}` use `{{ .Values.secret }}` and then when you run helm run it as for example `helm install chart --set secret=${SUPER_SECRET}`

Comment: I'd rather not use values if I can get away with it. Is there a reason why using the `env` function is properly incorrect? Am I misusing it somehow?

Comment: for example, your template, when evaluated by tiller on your kube cluster would have a completely different runtime ENV then the one you launch localy. Sidequestion: why would you prefer env var over value ?

Comment: I have a whole lot of secrets. So if I use `--set` then I have to set a lot of things, which I would store in my local environment anyway. So I figured I could remove a step and keep the process a little more DRY. Also I suppose I'm misunderstanding helm's process. I thought that the templates were rendered locally, I didn't realize that tiller rendered them.

Comment: Remember you don't need to supply all values each time you launch `helm upgrade`as you can use `--reuse-values` and only provide the changed ones (like new image tag) with `--set`. We use this in a flow when we first do a `helm install -f allthevalues.yml` and only do a `helm upgrade --reuse-values --set subchart.image.tag=v1.1.4` on releases of new version

Comment: this is not an answer to the question, unsure why it was marked as an answer.